# SaveURL and Returl on Choosing Pricebook on quote not working

Tags: visualforce

I am recreating the Add products page for quotes and i also want to have an option to choose the pricebook from Quotelineitems as well.

I am calling up the standard page for choosing pricebook

```
/_ui/sales/quote/lineitem/ChooseQuotePricebook/e?id=0Q0210000008hPsCAI&retURL=%2Fapex%2FaddQuotelines%3Fid%3D0Q0210000008hPsCAI&saveURL=%2Fapex%2FaddQuotelines%3Fid%3D0Q0210000008hPsCAI
```

When i click the save button it doesnt take me back to url given on the saveURL, but goes to the same choose pricebook url but without the id parameter and throws the following error.

> Unable to Access Page The value of a parameter contains a character
>   that is not allowed or the value exceeds the maximum allowed length.
>   Remove the character from the parameter value or reduce the value
>   length and resubmit. If the error still persists, report it to our
>   Customer Support team. Provide the URL of the page you were requesting
>   as well as any other related information.

```
public PageReference changePricebook(){

    // This simply returns a PageReference to the standard Pricebook selection screen
    // Note that is uses retURL parameter to make sure the user is sent back after they choose

    PageReference ref = new PageReference('/_ui/sales/quote/lineitem/ChooseQuotePricebook/e');
    ref.getParameters().put('id',theQuote.Id);
    ref.getParameters().put('retURL', '/apex/addQuotelines?id=' + theQuote.Id);
    ref.getParameters().put('saveURL','/apex/addQuotelines?id=' + theQuote.Id);
    return ref;
}
```

Am i missing something?

**UPDATE :** 
Its redirecting to my VF page if i click the cancel. but when i click on save it doesnt

Comment: not completely sure but i think you need to add  `save=1,`? can you try once?

Comment: Where would you want me to put save=1?

Comment: @sfdcweb that didnt work